# Change single-entry Israeli visa to multiple entry

Tags: visas, israel

I have a single-entry B2 visa for Israel and I am planning to spend 2 months in Tel Aviv as part of a university program. I would like to travel around the region during this time. Is it practically possible to convert my single-entry visa to a multiple-entry visa? The resources online do not give much detail about the documents required and the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it practically possible to convert my single-entry visa to a multiple-entry visa?

You'll need to apply for a new/extension visa. To do this from within the country follow the process [here](https://www.gov.il/en/service/schedule_meeting_visas_department).